# Can WebSphere MQ transfer file(e.g. *.txt) directly?

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm new to WebSphere MQ and I am trying to move files through WebSphere MQ as messages using c# code. Can WebSphere MQ transfer files (e.g. *.txt) directly?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The post title asks whether WMQ can transfer files but the body mentions WMQ File Transfer Edition. It is unclear which you are referring to.  Can you clarify?  Are you trying to write code to put files in messages? Or are you trying to drive FTE transfers from code?

Comment: Sorry for misleading.I have no WMQ File Transfer Edition,just want write code to put files in messages.Now I use FileStream to read file content as string,then put the string in message.Any way better?Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, base WebSphere MQ does not directly transfer files.  The semantics for moving files include such things as file names, directory paths, conversion of names across different types of filesystem (i.e. a UNIX filetree versus a z/OS Partitioned Dataset).  Messaging uses semantics specific to queues and topics and these are drastically different from those for files.

Accordingly, base WMQ does not attempt to perform file semantics as part of its core functionality.  The [WebSphere MQ File Transfer Edition](http://ibm.co/WMQFTE) and [IBM Sterling Connect:Direct](http://ibm.co/INdXGf) provide that functionality.  In the case of FTE, managed file transfer is natively built on top of WebSphere MQ.

Many people have in the past written solutions to move files using messaging, whether that's WebSphere MQ or another transport provider.  It turns out that doing so in a robust way is a non-trivial task.  Here are some of the issues:

- If you make each file a single message then message sizes vary considerably.  It is very difficult to tune the messaging engine to simultaneously perform with very large and very small messages.
- If you break the files up into chunks then you cna tune chunk size for optimal messaging performance but now you must deal with sequence preservation and resend of missing messages.
- The general problem of whether to append, replace or rename a destination file with the same name.
- The general problem of how to make the file available at the destination in a transactional manner.  You don't want the recipient to grab half a file.
- File integrity (FTE hashes the file to insure it doesn't get changed in transit).

These are a sampling of the issues to do this in a general-purpose way.  However if all you need is a one-time, point-to-point solution then have a look at [SupportPac MA01](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA01), the Q program.  It will take files and either put a line at a time into a message or make the entire file a single message.  It can also be used as a pipe so it's possible to have two instances of Q where one pipes messages to a queue and the other retrieves them.

Comment: Thank you very much!You mentioned the first issue,"It is very difficult to tune the messaging engine to simultaneously perform with very large and very small messages",what does it mean? It will lower the performance,right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The performance is important to application and must avoid halting data from flowing in channel.After getting the messages,we should release related resource,right?In my application,I invoke the qmgr.Disconnect() to release resource.Is that enough?Any better way?

Comment: Define "better way."  A couple of FTE agents will cost less than what you will spend trying to get the kinks ironed out of your homegrown version. And if you anticipate deploying to a large network of nodes that need to move files, the difference in performance, reliability and manageability will pay for the agents.  However, if you would still like to explore design options please ask a new question. SO doesn't work like a discussion forum but rather is driven by discrete questions and votes. A new question with its own tags and answers will better help the next person with a similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

WebSphere MQ File Transfer Edition (FTE) is a product built on top of WebSphere MQ for transferring files. No coding is required to for transferring files. There are commands and MQ Explorer through which you can configure your file transfers. You can also start file transfers through scripting.

Read through this developerWorks [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1003_phillips/1003_phillips.html)

Comment: Sorry for misleading,but I have no FTE.Maybe I must write code to transfer file myself.Also thank you!